# Custom Jetson Nano Carrier Board 4A trace width connections

Tags: pcb, autorouter, jetson

Hi I'm designing a custom Jetson Nano Carrier Board according to Jetson_Nano_Carrier_Board_OrCAD_Schematics file. And as may you know, from DC Jack you can supply 5V 4A to the board. The problem is, trace width for 4A literally 50mil while rest of the connections are 6mil. So I try to keep it minimum as possible but according to this schematic file, which traces carry 4A and should be 50mil width? We assume VDD_5V_In carry 4A in here. We can't decide right now, I really need help thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your schematics are blurred and unreadable.

Comment: Use Saturn PCB Design.exe tool to compute temp rise of various trace cross-sectional area for temp rise and length for voltage drop. And be conservative. Also a 4A jack will eventually get hot from oxidizing and melt if you use 4A. Never use max rating for long life. Been there done that.

Comment: 50 mil is 1.27mm. Seems reasonable. I'd use 2mm trace widths for that amout of current. Or draw some planes.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm sorry I'm going to update

Answer (score 0):

Beside the trace width, you can also increase the copper thickness like 1oz,2oz,etc.

You can check your pcb manufacturer capabilities.

Besides of that, you can do smaller trace for shorter distance, the trade-off are some voltage drop and some heat.

Comment: Thank you but from the schematics, which traces should be thicker like which trace 4A would follow?

Comment: Right by the connector if the pitch is too small for example